# Updating or deleting d3.slider with variation of visualization

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to visualize data on a map over time and per day. Therefore I got two functions which are plotting points over a day and remove themselves after the day has passed

```
var showOne = function (){
  var slider = d3.slider()
      .axis(true).min(minDate).max(maxDate)
      .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
        sliderDate = moment(value,"x").utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        newDataS = site_dataS.features.filter(function(d){
          dataDate = d.properties.Date;
          if (dataDate == sliderDate) {
            return dpS(dataDate);
          }
        });
        displaySitesS(newDataS);
      })

  d3.select('#slider3').call(slider);

}
```

and I have this function which shows incidents over time

```
var showTwo = function (){
  d3.select('#slider3').call(d3.slider()
    .axis(true).min(minDate).max(maxDate)
    .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
      sliderDate = moment(value,"x").utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      newDataS = site_dataS.features.filter(function(d){
        return dpS(d.properties.Date) < new Date(value);

      });

      displaySitesS(newDataS);
    })
  );
}
```

I want to update the slider with a button

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/d3.slider.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/temp.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/d3.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/socket.io-0.9.10.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/caress-0.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/d3.tip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://riccardoscalco.github.io/textures/textures.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- <script>
    $(function() {
        window.client = new Caress.Client({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 5000
        });
        client.connect();
    });
  </script> -->
<div id="slider3"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/04map.js"></script>



<div class="chart"></div>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/streamgraphTexture.js"></script> -->
<button>Zeige alle</button>
<script>
showOne();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(showTwo);
});
</script>


</body>
```

But the another slider is added right beneath the old slider. Do you have some ideas how to update the slider so it can be used for other the visualization? All data is [here](https://github.com/RitterLean/Slider-data)

[image: Error]

EDIT1:

```
var width = 1020,
    height = 500;
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .scale((width - 1) / 2 / Math.PI);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([3, 200])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .html(function(d) { return d.properties.description })
  .offset([0, 3]);



var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g");
svg.call(tip)

var g = svg.append("g");
var sites = svg.append("g");
var graph = svg.append("g");

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

svg.call(zoom)
    .call(zoom.event);

d3.json("mapdata/worldfill.json", function(error, world) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries_fill).features;

  g.append("path")
      .datum({type: "Sphere"})
      .attr("class", "sphere")
      .attr("d", path);

  g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.merge(world, world.objects.countries_fill.geometries))
      .attr("class", "land")
      .attr("d", path);

  g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries_fill, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "boundary")
      .attr("d", path);
//_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
//________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________


  d3.json("mapdata/germany.json", function(error, ger){
    if (error) throw error;
    var states = topojson.feature(ger, ger.objects.states_germany),
        cities = topojson.feature(ger, ger.objects.cities_germany);

    g.selectAll(".states")
        .data(states.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "state")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "state " + d.id; })
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return z(d.id);
        });
    g.append("path")
        .datum(cities)
        .attr("d", path.pointRadius('0.35'))
        .style("opacity", 0.5)
        .style("fill", "blue")
        .attr("class", "city");


      g.selectAll(".german-place-label")
          .data(cities.features)
          .enter().append("text")
          .attr("class", "place-label")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });
  });

  d3.json("mapdata/syria.json", function(error, syr){
    if (error) throw error;
    var states = topojson.feature(syr, syr.objects.states_syria),
        cities = topojson.feature(syr, syr.objects.cities_syria);

    g.selectAll(".states")
        .data(states.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "state")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "state " + d.id; })
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("fill", "orange");
    // g.append("path")
    //     .datum(cities)
    //     .attr("d", path.pointRadius('0.15'))
    //     .attr("class", "city");

    // g.selectAll(".syrian-place-label")
    //     .data(cities.features)
    //     .enter().append("text")
    //     .attr("class", "place-label")
    //     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; })
    //     .attr("dy", ".35em")
    //     .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });

  });

});

function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  sites.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  //console.log(sites.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"));
}


d3.json("data/vorfaelle.json", function(error, data){
    window.site_dataG = data;
});
d3.json("data/syria05.json", function(error, data){
    window.site_dataS = data;
});

d3.json("data/deathineurope.json", function(error, data){
    window.site_dataW = data;
});

d3.json("data/isil.en.json", function(error, data){
    window.site_dataB = data;
    console.log("Loaded");
});




var displaySitesG = function(data) {
  var sitedata = sites.selectAll(".siteG")
      .data(data);

  sitedata
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "siteG")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[0];
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[1]
      })
      .on("click", tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
      .attr("r", 1.25)
      .transition().duration(70)
      .attr("r", 5);
      // .on("mouseover", tip.show);
      // .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      //       div.transition()
      //           .duration(200)
      //           .style("opacity", 0.9);
      //       // div.html("Test")
      //           // .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      //           // .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
      //       })
        // .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        //     div.transition()
        //         .duration(500)
        //         .style("opacity", 0);
        // });


    sitedata.exit()//remove the selection which are to be removed from dataset
      //.transition().duration(200)
        .attr("r",0)
        .remove();

};

var displaySitesS = function(data) {
  var radScale = d3.scale.linear()
    // .domain([0,d3.max(data, function (d) {
    //   return d.properties.Value
    // })])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
      return d.properties.Value
    }))
    .range([0.1,.5]);
  var siteDataS = sites.selectAll(".siteS")
      .data(data);
  siteDataS
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "siteS")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[0];
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[1]
      })
      .attr("r", function(d){
        return 1.75 * radScale(d.properties.Value)
      })
      .transition().duration(70)
      .attr("r", function(d){
        return radScale(d.properties.Value)
      });

    siteDataS.exit()//remove the selection which are to be removed from dataset
        .transition().duration(10)
        .attr("r",0)
        .remove();

};


var displaySitesW = function(data) {


  var siteDataW = sites.selectAll(".siteW")
      .data(data);


  siteDataW
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "siteW")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[0];
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[1]
      })
      .attr("r", 10)
      .transition().duration(70)
      .attr("r", 20);

    siteDataW.exit()//remove the selection which are to be removed from dataset
        .transition().duration(500).delay(1000)
        .attr("r",0)
        .style("opacity", 0.5)
        .remove();

};

var displaySitesB = function(data) {

  var radScale = d3.scale.linear()
    // .domain([0,d3.max(data, function (d) {
    //   return d.properties.Value
    // })])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
      return d.properties.attacks
    }))
    .range([1,4]);

  var siteDataB = sites.selectAll(".siteB")
      .data(data);
  siteDataB
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "siteB")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[0];
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[1]
      })
      .attr("r", 2)
      .transition().duration(70)
      .attr("r", function(d){
        return radScale(d.properties.attacks)
      });
    siteDataB.exit()//remove the selection which are to be removed from dataset
        .transition().duration(500)
        .attr("r",0)
        .style("opacity", 0.5)
        .remove();
};


dpG = d3.time.format("%d.%m.%Y").parse;
dpS = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
var minDate = dpG("01.01.2015");
var maxDate = dpG("31.12.2015");
var secondsInDay = 60 * 60 * 24;


var slider = d3.slider()
    .axis(true).min(minDate).max(maxDate)
    .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
      sliderDate = moment(value,"x").utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

      newDataS = site_dataS.features.filter(function(d){
        dataDate = d.properties.Date;
        if (dataDate == sliderDate) {
          return dpS(dataDate);
        }
      });
      displaySitesS(newDataS);
    })
    d3.select('#slider3').call(slider);

var showOne = function (){
    slider = d3.slider()
      .axis(true).min(minDate).max(maxDate)
      .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
        sliderDate = moment(value,"x").utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

        newDataS = site_dataS.features.filter(function(d){
          dataDate = d.properties.Date;
          if (dataDate == sliderDate) {
            return dpS(dataDate);
          }
        });
//______________________________________________________________________________
//______________________________________________________________________________

        // newdataW =  site_dataW.features.filter(function(d){
        //   dataDate = d.properties.date;
        //   if (dataDate == sliderDate) {
        //     //console.log(dpS(dataDate));
        //     //console.log(dpS(dataDate));
        //     return dpS(dataDate);
        //   }
        // });
//______________________________________________________________________________
//______________________________________________________________________________
        //
        // newdataB =  site_dataB.features.filter(function(d){
        //   dataDate = d.properties.date;
        //   if (dataDate == sliderDate) {
        //     //console.log(dpS(dataDate));
        //     //console.log(dpS(dataDate));
        //     return dpS(dataDate);
        //   }
        // });

//______________________________________________________________________________
//______________________________________________________________________________

        displaySitesS(newDataS);
        //displaySitesW(newdataW);
        //displaySitesB(newdataB);
      })

  d3.select('#slider3').call(slider);

}

var showTwo = function (){
  console.log("ShowTwoNow");
  d3.select('#slider3').remove(slider);

  slider = d3.slider()
    //.axis(true).min(minDate).max(maxDate)
    .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
      sliderDate = moment(value,"x").utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      newDataS = site_dataS.features.filter(function(d){
        return dpS(d.properties.Date) < new Date(value);

      });

      displaySitesS(newDataS);

    })
    d3.select('#slider3').call(slider);

}
```

I may remove the slider but then of course the DOM element removed too. But how can call another slider with new a new filter-function if I can't update it?

Comment: This link will help you https://bl.ocks.org/caravinden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am calling the slider once now but inside the slider I let a variable decide which filter-function it should use. The whole code looks like this then

```
   // var siteDataW,
    //     siteDataS,
    //     siteDataG;


var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .html(function(d) { return d.properties.description })
  .offset([0, 3]);
svg.call(tip)


function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  sites.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  var translate = zoom.translate();
  var translateX = translate[0]/zoom.scale();
  var translateY = translate[1]/zoom.scale();
  // console.log(translate[0]/zoom.scale() + "   " + translate[1]/zoom.scale());
  // console.log(zoom.scale());

  if (zoom.scale()<minZoomTresholdCountry) {
    //console.log("WELT");
    zoomCheck = 0;
    // if( siteDataG ){
    //   siteDateG.remove();
    // }
    // if(siteDataS){
    //   siteDataS.remove();
    // }
  }
  else if(zoom.scale() >= minZoomTresholdCountry
    && translateX< minXG && translateX > maxXG
    && translateY<minYG && translateY>maxYG){
      //console.log("DE");
      zoomCheck = 1;
  }
  else if(zoom.scale() >= minZoomTresholdCountry
    && translateX> minXS && translateX < maxXS
    && translateY<minYS && translateY>maxYS){
      //console.log("SYR");
      zoomCheck = 2;
  }
  else{
    zoomCheck = 0;
  }
  console.log(zoomCheck)
}


d3.json("data/vorfaelle.json", function(error, data){
    window.site_dataG = data;
});
d3.json("data/syria05.json", function(error, data){
    window.site_dataS = data;
});

d3.json("data/deathineurope.json", function(error, data){
    window.site_dataW = data;
});

d3.json("data/isil.en.json", function(error, data){
    window.site_dataB = data;
});

dpG = d3.time.format("%d.%m.%Y").parse;
dpS = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
dpS = function(){
  d3.time.parse;
}
dpsTimestamp = +dpS;

var minDate = dpG("01.01.2015");
var maxDate = dpG("31.12.2015");

var slider = d3.slider()
    .axis(true).min(minDate).max(maxDate).step(60 * 60 * 24)
    .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
      sliderDate = moment(value,"x").utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      console.log(sliderDate);
      if( filterCheck == 0 ){

        if( zoomCheck == 0 ){

          newDataW = site_dataW.features.filter(function(d){
            dataDate = d.properties.date;
            if (dataDate == sliderDate) {
              return dpS(dataDate);
            }
          });

          showWorldSite(newDataW)

        }

        else if( zoomCheck == 1 ){
        sliderDate = moment(value,"x").utc().format("MM.DD.YYYY");

          newDataG = site_dataG.features.filter(function(d){
            dataDate = d.properties.date;
            if (dataDate == sliderDate) {
              console.log(dpG(dataDate))
              return dpG(dataDate)
            }
          })
          showGermanSite(newDataG);
        }

        else if( zoomCheck == 2 ){

          newDataS = site_dataS.features.filter(function(d){
            dataDate = d.properties.Date;
            if (dataDate == sliderDate) {
              return dpS(dataDate);
            }
          });

          showSyrianSite(newDataS);
        }

      }
//================================================================================================
//================================================================================================
//================================================================================================

      else if( filterCheck == 1 ) {

        if( zoomCheck == 0 ){

          newDataW = site_dataW.features.filter(function(d){
            return dpS(d.properties.date) < new Date(value);
          });

          showWorldSite(newDataW)

        }

        else if( zoomCheck == 1 ){

          newDataG = site_dataG.features.filter(function(d){
            dataDate = d.properties.Date;
            return dpS(dataDate) < dpS(sliderDate);
          })
          console.log(newDataG.length);
          console.log(new Date(value));
          showGermanSite(newDataG);
        }

        else if( zoomCheck == 2 ){

          newDataS = site_dataS.features.filter(function(d){
            return dpS(d.properties.Date) < new Date(value);
          });

          showSyrianSite(newDataS);
        }

      }





    });

d3.select('#slider3').call(slider);

function showWorldSite(data){

    var siteDataW = sites.selectAll(".siteW")
        .data(data);
    siteDataW
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "siteW")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
          return p[0];
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
          return p[1]
        })
        .attr("r", 20)
        .transition().duration(70)
        .attr("r", 10);

      siteDataW.exit()//remove the selection which are to be removed from dataset
          .transition().duration(500).delay(1000)
          .attr("r",0)
          .style("opacity", 0.5)
          .remove();
}
function showGermanSite(data){


  var sitedataG = sites.selectAll(".siteG")
      .data(data);
  sitedataG
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "siteG")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[0];
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[1]
      })
      .on("click", tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
      .attr("r", 1.25)
      .transition().duration(70)
      .attr("r", 0.25);
    sitedataG.exit()//remove the selection which are to be removed from dataset
      //.transition().duration(200)
        .attr("r",0)
        .remove();

}

function showSyrianSite(data){
  var radScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
      return d.properties.Value }))
    .range([0.1,.5]);
  var siteDataS = sites.selectAll(".siteS")
      .data(data);
  siteDataS
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "siteS")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[0];
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        var p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        return p[1]
      })
      .attr("r", function(d){
        return 1.75 * radScale(d.properties.Value)
      })
      .transition().duration(70)
      .attr("r", function(d){
        return radScale(d.properties.Value)
      });

    siteDataS.exit()//remove the selection which are to be removed from dataset
        .transition().duration(10)
        .attr("r",0)
        .remove();


}
```